# Power BI conditional column between two dates

Tags: powerbi, conditional-statements, powerbi-desktop

I’m trying to insert a *conditional column* in the Power Query Editor where if a date falls between *certain* dates, a specific value is added. The dates and values are listed below.

I have attached a screenshot of my attempt, but the results stop at 51 and do no increase from there.

Where am I going wrong with this? It’s almost as if it needs a Between argument, but is this possible in the Power Query Editor?

**Dates & Values:**

Before 18/07/2022 = 31

On or After 18/07/2022 & Before 08/08/2022 = 51

On or After 08/08/2022 & Before 30/08/2022 = 71

On or After 30/08/2022 = 91

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *if* statement searches for the first TRUE() value and returns it. In your case, you use condition "after or equal", so every date with value >=18/07/2022 gets 51, because it is the first True value.

Try to change the order:

1. is before 18/07/2022 = 31
2. after or equal to 30/08/2022 = 91
3. after or equal to 08/08/2022 = 71
4. after or equal to 18/07/2022 = 51

Comment: Perfect! thanks for your help on this one Mik, much appreciated.